# NumberPicker's onClick listener takes multiple clicks to recognise

Tags: android, numberpicker, android-bottomsheetdialog

I want to make sure that user clicks on the value in the number picker, and once done, I take an action. I've written the code below. The numberPicker is created in a bottomSheetDialogFragment.

```
nPicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    NumberPicker p = v.findViewById(R.id.numberpicker_picker);
    Log.e("picker selected", ""+p.getValue());
}
```

The above code works fine to an extent, but it have to click on the numberpicker a bunch of times before the click is recognised.

Does anyone know why that is and if there's a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the `onValueChangeListener()`. The clicks are probably getting consumed by this listener, so your `onClick(View v)` isn't working.

```
numberPicker.setOnValueChangedListener((numberPicker, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    Log.e("picker selected", ""+newValue);
});
```

Comment: I am using valueChangeListener as well, but even that doesnt print log when I click on the item in picker. It takes some 3-4 clicks to get through. (and sometimes, happens on the first click)